# How to make sure an application scoped bean will initialize before all others?

Tags: jsf

I have two application scoped beans which initialize on startup. Both are annotated with

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
```

The thing is, one of the beans have to be instantiated and "PostConstructed" before the other. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure but Injection could help on that?

Comment: Injecting one into the other should work. Generally, Spring at least avoids letting you specify load order of beans explicitly. The idea is that there's a reason why you want one to initialise before the others, and that this reason should be expressed using dependencies between beans instead of a fragile absolute ordering. Any absolute startup code belongs into `main()` or a `ServletContextListener`, not bean initialisers.

Comment: @millimoose yours was a great comment. What you've stated makes perfect sense. I'll seriously consider changing my strategy regarding these two beans.

Comment: @Tuan Dang I do not use Spring, and this question is about JSF in general, so I don't know why you have added the spring tag

Comment: @FelipeReis I thought the annotations are in `Spring Framework`. Sorry!! Could you edit your question with some comments to remove the `tag`?

Comment: No worries Tuan :) I have corrected the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First option** would be to do a Singleton

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class SingletonBean
{
    private static SingletonBean m_oInstance;

    public static SingletonBean getInstance()
    {
        if(m_oInstance == null)
        {
            m_oInstance = (SingletonBean)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("singletonBean");

            // Just in case our instance is not already in the FacesContext
            if(m_oInstance == null)
            {
                m_oInstance = new SingletonBean();

                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().put("singletonBean",m_oInstance);
            }
        }

        return m_oInstance;
    }
}
```

And you only have to call if from other beans :

```
SingletonBean.getInstance();
```

**A second option** I've just tested that doesn't looks like the most elegant but could do the job is by adding `@ManagedProperty` to all `@ApplicationScoped` beans that need to be loaded in **second**, it permits to force loading the first bean in first time.

**First bean**

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationScopeZ
{
    public ApplicationScopeZ()
    {
        System.out.println("ApplicationScopeZ - constructor");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {
        System.out.println("ApplicationScopeZ - init");
    }
}
```

**Second bean**

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationScopeA
{
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{applicationScopeZ}")
    ApplicationScopeZ applicationScopeZ;

    public ApplicationScopeA()
    {
        System.out.println("ApplicationScopeA - constructor");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {
        System.out.println("ApplicationScopeA - init");
    }

    public void setapplicationScopeZ(ApplicationScopeZ p_oApplicationScopeZ)
    {
        applicationScopeZ = p_oApplicationScopeZ;
    }
}
```

**Third bean**

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationScopeO
{
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{applicationScopeZ}")
    ApplicationScopeZ applicationScopeZ;

    public ApplicationScopeO()
    {
        System.out.println("ApplicationScopeO - constructor");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {
        System.out.println("ApplicationScopeO - init");
    }

    public void setapplicationScopeZ(ApplicationScopeZ p_oApplicationScopeZ)
    {
        applicationScopeZ = p_oApplicationScopeZ;
    }
}
```

Starting the application with this configuration using Mojarra 2.1.14, it is giving this output :

```
ApplicationScopeZ - constructor
ApplicationScopeZ - init
ApplicationScopeO - constructor
ApplicationScopeO - init
ApplicationScopeA - constructor
ApplicationScopeA - init
```

As we can see, the **First bean** (ApplicationScopeZ) is loaded in first, even with a name that *should* be ordered at the end.

Doing the same by removing all injection related code is giving this output :

```
ApplicationScopeA - constructor
ApplicationScopeA - init
ApplicationScopeO - constructor
ApplicationScopeO - init
ApplicationScopeZ - constructor
ApplicationScopeZ - init
```

In conclusion, the order was changed by the injection.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, this was a great answer.

Comment: Singleton approach in 1st option is absolutely not recommended. If one depends on other, just inject it as in 2nd option.

Comment: @BalusC The first option have the advantage of being more portable from a project to another (ie : library) but I'm pretty sure there is a better option that I don't know yet!

Comment: Portability is not the issue. Design is the issue. See also http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SingletonVsJustCreateOne Just make it a property of an application scoped bean for which it's already been guaranteed that there's only one instance applicationwide.